# Creating a custom control in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, controls, custom-controls, xamarin

I'm porting my app from Windows Phone 8 to Android - and I need to create a few custom UI controls. I tried to create an XML layout, creating a LinearLayout inside it as the control and then add it dynamically (After user's desire) - but that didn't work. How can I accomplish this the easiest way as possible?

This is the code i tried:

MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Knowledge_Organizer
{
[Activity (Label = "Knowledge_Organizer", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Import the items from resources
        LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.rootLayout);

        // Add the tile
        Resource.Layout.Tile tileRoot = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Layout.Tile);
        var tile = (Resource.Id.projectTile);
        layout.AddView (tile);
    }
}
}
```

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout" />
```

Tile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#ff2e4653">
    <TextView
        android:text="Project"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/projectTile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Kind Regards,
Erik

Comment: So, how does the `Tile.cs` fill look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a LayoutInflater, e.g.

```
var tile = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_tile_xml, null);
layout.AddView (tile);
```

To find a control within the tile:

```
var tile = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_tile_xml, null);
tile.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.projectTile).Text = "whatever";
layout.AddView (tile);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked - but how can I modify one specific control within the tile? Keep in mind the tile will be added dynamically after the user's desire

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how to set the text. If the answer worked for you, you should mark it as correct. That's how this site works.