# Xamarin.Android Creating And Using Custom Controls

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Another tough day with Xamarin!

So, today, i am trying to figure out how one can create and use a custom control in `Xamarin.Android`. I read all the docs and all were on `Xamarin.Forms`. I wonder why there is so less support for `Xamarin.Android`.

Anyways, i came across a few questions on SO and tried this :

**TestControl.cs**

```
namespace TestApp.CustomControls.Classes
{
public class TestControl : ViewGroup
{
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public TestControl(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }
}
}
```

**TestControl.xml**

```
<TestApp.CustomControls.Classes.TestControl xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_width="20dp"
                                                 android:background="#fff">
```

In my **activity_main.axml** file, i have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_weight="50dp">

<TestApp.CustomControls.Classes.TestControl android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_weight="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Even though intellisense is able to find `TestApp.CustomControls.Classes.TestControl` but i don't see anything on the screen. Maybe because i never linked the xml file with the class?(Still now sure how xamarin.android works).

So, what should be my steps to get the custom control working/visible on view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682010/creating-a-custom-control-in-xamarin

Comment: It is a ViewGroup subclass, thus is a container for other `View`s and/or to describe layout parameters of its children, what do you expect to see when it does does not contain any children?

Comment: @SushiHangover, umm, i tried adding a `<LinearLayout>` to the Xml file but didn't result in anything.... Maybe i am missing a lot here. Any guidance?

Comment: @Jason, i've already seen that question. So, where is the `Tile.cs` ? How does it actually look like? And the way his, `Tile.xml` looked....well, how is he supposed to connect the control's code-behind with the xml?

Comment: @zackraiyan A LinearLayout is a ViewGroup subclass and again is a container for other controls that provides an vert/horz. layout of its children based upon its orientation property (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout). What are you trying to accomplish with your "custom control"?

Comment: @SushiHangover Well, i come from a WPF background. So i am trying to achieve custom looks using custom controls and so that i can generate them on demand. I will also set-up required dependency properties.

Comment: @zackraiyan WPF has container controls like Panels, ScrollViewer, etc.... same for Android, it has ViewGroup subclasses... your description of what you want is way to vague, maybe start with by learning what the stock set of Android containers widgets can/can't do for your design requirements and focus on subclassing and enhancing those (before rewriting containers and widgets from scratch) so you can write a descriptive requirement of what you are trying to accomplish. Google has complete guides of what the GUI framework provides out of the box : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui

Comment: @SushiHangover, just one quick question. If i follow [this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682010/creating-a-custom-control-in-xamarin), how am i supposed to connect the view with the class(xml with the code-behind file)? Is just the name of the XML file that has to be same of the class name and the linking would happen by itself?

Comment: Same as WPF XAML,  your Android AXML gets inflated into instances of the classes it contains at runtime.... If the Activity/Fragment/ViewGroup/... needs to access an instance within a layout that it is inflating, you can use `FindViewById`...

Comment: Shouldn't it inherit from View rather than from ViewGroup? ViewGroup is a container for views AFAIK

Comment: @MatheusRocha Yes, indeed. However i fixed the issue ages ago.